# What is generatedJava package in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

today i updated Android Studio to v3.2 and a new package (generatedJava) added to project, what is this and why this should be important to developer to see in android studio project section?

[image]

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52400081/how-to-remove-generatedjava-from-android-studio-3-2 It is autogenerated by AS itself. There were no options to remove it nor, hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Kotlin Fundamentals - Explore Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-get-started?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#3)

> Note the generatedJava folder. This folder contains files that Android Studio generates when it builds the app. Don't edit anything in this folder, because your changes might be overridden when you rebuild the app. But it's useful to know about this folder when you need to look at these files during debugging