# I can't find R.java folder, has it been renamed in version 3.3?

Tags: android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXg16.png)I can't find and locate the R.java folder. Has it been renamed? I looked everywhere in the drop down tabs from Project Files, Android, and Packages.

Answer (score 0):

Closer enough to be a duplicated of [Android Studio 3.2 Generated java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52548924/android-studio-3-2-generated-java) but the path had a little change:

> app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/developDebug/processDevelopDebugResources/r/your/project/package/R.java

The path won't be accesible from Android Studio, instead, it is accessible from your OS File Manager (Explorer in your case)

Run clean project and the path should appear.

Comment: I ran clean project as well as rebuild project, also closed the app and re-opened. Still can't locate the R.java folder. I'm going to check my other projects to see if I can find the folder.

Comment: Okay so it shows on 2 of my previous projects I worked on. However it is still not showing on the one I am working on. I am going to start over, however if anyone finds out why this happened feel free to reply.

Comment: Good, my new answer turns this question as duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52548924/android-studio-3-2-generated-java because in Android Studio 3.3 the path is the same as I post in my answer.